# is there any problem if i reset my unrooted andoif mobile that is previously rooted?

Tags: root-access

My phones play store is not connecting to internet it shows connection error.... and some of the app is not connecting to internet. I think factory reset may solve this problem but I have rooted my phone and then unrooted. what will happened if I reset my phone?   device name : Intex Aqua Q5 (released recently) currently no firmwares available on the internet.  Android Version : 4.4 kitkat

Comment: *"what will [happen] if I reset my phone?"* -- take backup first. You would lose third-party apps, apps data, all custom settings and more. I don't know how your stock recovery would reset the phone so take backup of internal SD card as well.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). Instead of trying to get your supposed solution working: Why not rather asking the real question? Have you checked with the first-aid given in our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info)?

Answer (score 0):

Resetting your phone won't cause any problems, but all third party apps will uninstalled. If you don't want to reset you could try booting into safe mode instead.